# Wordpress REST API response slowly

Tags: wordpress

I've created a few API endpoints for a Wordpress site. 12 external Websites send data to the Wordpress site. I noticed, that since the Wordpress site has a huge amount of data the response-time increased. Do you have any tips to get a faster response?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [WP REST API Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-cache/) plugin? It will enable caching for WordPress REST API and increase speed of your API request.

Comment: Which method did you use to send request? If not GET request, it takes time for handling by server.

Comment: I use only POST requests. Yes for sure, but the time gets longer if the site has more posts - could this be?

Comment: So [Query Monitor](https://vi.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) is the plugin I think you will need. Take a look at your slow queries in your backend. I know the information Query Monitor plugin provide in API request is not too much, but I think you will see what slow you down.

After you find out what queries are slow (if it is), you might want to add index to some column that needs to. See example: https://guides.wp-bullet.com/add-mysql-index-wordpress-wp_options-table/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this for the reasons for slow response times, it might be due to all the things that load
[slow response times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45421976/7142607)