# Headless Wordpress REST API Slow Response Time (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api

I am building a static site and calling data from Wordpress API via Fetch API. It's taking about 650ms per response, which isn't terrible but it does make the website feel slow. Is there any way in JavaScript to get this response time down?

From [this post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421976/wordpress-rest-api-slow-response-time) it seems that WP loads all of its core with every response, which would definitely account for the slow speed. The solution in that post though seems to be using PHP, where as I am making calls on client side JS and therefore I don't believe that is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried above things via code than I would suggest to go with Rest API Caching plugins. Below are the couple of suggestions for Rest API Cache.

Free version of https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-cache/ 
and
Paid version of https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Thanks 
Jenil